# bootstrap navbar collaspe not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've followed a lot of tips on here but I still don't get my links stacked in smaller screen mode (the three bar icon does appear but doesn't respond)  Code is as follows, would really appreciate any help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Learn Spanish noun gender easily</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5
    elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/ 3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>

    .box    {
        border:solid grey;
        background-color:#d3d3d3;
            }


    #div1 {
         background-image: url('images/cherry.jpg');
        }

    #div2 {
         background-image: url('images/lavender.jpg');
        }
    #div3 {
         background-image: url('images/rose.jpg');
        }

    .contentDiv {
        height:800px;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        font-size:1.7em;
    }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Learn Spanish noun Genders</a>

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>


            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="active"><a href="#div1">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#div2">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#div3">Download</a></li>

                </ul>


            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


        <div id="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 box"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 box">Content</div>
                <div class="col-md-4 box">Content</div>


            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container">


        <div id="div1" class="contentDiv"><p>Content and some more lalalalalallalala</p></div>
        <div id="div2" class="contentDiv">Content</div>
        <div id="div3" class="contentDiv">Content</div>


        </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript --> 
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your nav:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Learn Spanish noun Genders</a>
 </div>

 <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#div1">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#div2">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#div3">Download</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have done mistake in buttons **data-toggle** attribute

it should be **data-toggle** not **datatoggle**

after changing this code will work